# Safari and Google Chrome orientation scale

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-safari

one of my friends create a web mobile and it shows me some problem when orientate mobile. It looks great but it shows me a problem when user change orientation. Website is http://www.tivag.ch/app. When page is loading it works fine in portrait mode, when i change in landscape mode also works perfect, but when i return back in portrait mode it shows me a problem it shows me a blank white space in right. When page is return in portrait mode document.width keeps the width of the landscape mode, it does not change the value. Scale doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden;` for .content elememt.

```
.content {
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden; /*Important*/
height: auto;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 15px;
background: url(../img/bg_content.jpg) no-repeat center top;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

As well as for further consistent results Add it to your head section. And don't use minimum-scale="1"

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0">
```